# What is this in SCSS it was in the style code: #{&}

Tags: sass, styles

```
@if $media == mobile {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) { @content; }
    @at-root {
      .l-grid.mobile #{&} { @content; }
    }
  }
```

what does it means? #{&}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` outputs the parent selector.

Normal cases are for appending pseudo-classes like `:hover` using

`.selector{
  color: #000;
  &:hover{
    color: #fff;
  }
}`

Which outputs:

`.selector{
  color: #000;
}
.selector:hover{
  color: #fff;
}`

---

When using `@at-root` this allows you to keep the parent selector while moving the element out of the parent.

`.class:after{
  content: 'Just any .class element';
  @at-root{
    div#{&}{
      content: 'A .class DIV element';
    }
  }
}`

In this case `#{&}` is the equivalent to `.class:after`.

The above will output to:

`.class:after{
  content: 'Just any .class element';
}
div.class:after{
  content: 'A .class DIV element;
}`

---

See this article for more information: http://sassbreak.com/getting-back-to-our-roots/#modify-an-elements-use-of-a-class